# Committed records getting rolled back when exception occurs

Tags: jpa, jdbc, db2, ejb

As per my understanding, committed records will never get roll back in ideal case. But committed records are really getting rolled back for the below code. I'm not sure this is done by JTA or by database which delete committed records when referenced parent table got roll back.

I will explain my scenario with the below simple code snippet. My transactional method `createItems(List<items> items)` will create list of parent items by calling `itemService.saveParent(items)`. This will do `flush()` and then `prepareChild(parentItems)` will create thousands of child items for each parent items where child item will set primary key of parent item as its foreign key. Now I'm calling `saveChild(subList)` by making chunks (because I do not want to commit 1 million record with single transaction) and its transactional attribute is `REQUIRES_NEW` which will commit each sublist to DB. But one of the chunk got exception. When I checked the DB I saw that all inserted child records rolled back. How this happened for committed records ?

And If roll back would'n have happened, then how child records can exist when the parent records already got rolled back and no PK exist ?

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class Job {

    @EJB
    private ItemService itemService;

    public void createItems(List<items> items) {

        List<Parent> parentItems = itemService.saveParent(items);

        List<Child> childItems = itemService.prepareChild(parentItems);

        for(List<Child> subList: getSublist(childItems )) {
            itemService.saveChild(subList);
        }

    }
}


@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class ItemService {

    @EJB
    private ItemDLService itemDLService;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveChild(List<child> childList) {

        itemDLService.save(childList);

    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, the database is likely protecting you - it can't reasonably commit child records if the parent record isn't committed, because if the parent record ends up rolled back the child records would point to a parent record that doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean to say child records are not actually committed when referencing parent records are not yet committed, even if they are part of different transaction ? Makes sense. Then I have one doubt here. For the ideal situation, commit will happen only after the outer method (createItems()) finishes ? Then this will make concern from DB side. The whole intention here is to have intermediate commit to avoid longer transaction.

Comment: ... you'd need to explicitly commit the parent transaction first, then.  Or push them over the wire into a (session-created) temp table, then move the entire set to the target table in one transaction (which, being database-only, will be shorter).  Or, depending on what other things your application is doing, just eat the transaction time; except in extreme cases the rest of the table is still updatable.  How many rows are we talking about here, anyways?

Comment: For the parent table there are less than 500 and child will be around 200 thousands. We have an SLA of one minute for entire processing. Let me ask you one doubt, If we have to achieve unitOfWork(with transaction) and same time we need to have intermediate commit (To avoid concern from DB people), what could be the common design approach? Because this looks common usecase.

Comment: Your SLA is a separate concern, and you'd actually spend additional time with chunked transactions (due to the extra work).  Probably your best bet to avoid a long coarse lock on a common table (which is what the DBAs would worry about) is to load into a non-journaled temp table the 200k rows, then start your transaction and insert the parent records and move the child records.  Bulk-loading the 200k records should be doable, which will also improve the time here as well.

Comment: Note, however, that with a good flushing strategy and query rewriting it seems like this should be doable in ~10 seconds, even without bulk-load tricks.  You still couldn't **commit** the records until the end, though, and I don't think nested transactions would help (DB2s `SAVEPOINT` functionality) with the lock coarseness/escalation.